# Run many Angular-Meteor webs on 1 VPS

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, meteor, webserver, vps

I have 2 webs application deleloped by Angular-Meteor framework.
I want to deploy them on 1 VPS (Ubuntu).
Each web is run on difference port: 
    web1.com runs on port 88 (meteor --port 88),
    web2.net runs on port 99 (meteor --port 99).

Now, How can I config to:
    If user types web1.com on browser -> web1.com will response.
    If user types web2.net on browser -> web2.net will response.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of nginx and mup to do this.
Check the [docs here](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up#multiple-deployments).